# github pages перекидывает не туда куда надо

Tags: git, github, github-pages

У меня вопрос почему при нажатии на ссылку https://thedifferentguy.github.io/My-first-project.github.io/, которая стоит в репозитории. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Меня перекидывает сюда?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста!!!!!

Comment: В чем заключается ваш вопрос? Куда вы ожидаете, чтобы вас перекидывало?

Comment: Переименуйте файл `main.html` в `index.html`

Answer (score 0):

На главной странице https://pages.github.com/ написано, чтобы создать статический сайт, нужно репозиторий назвать в соответствии с вашим именем пользователя:

> Head over to GitHub and create a new public repository named username.github.io, where username is your username (or organization name) on GitHub. 
>  **If the first part of the repository doesn’t exactly match your username, it won’t work, so make sure to get it right.**

Переименуйте ваш репозиторий из [`My-first-project.github.io`](https://github.com/TheDifferentGuy/My-first-project.github.io) в [`TheDifferentGuy.github.io`](https://github.com/TheDifferentGuy/TheDifferentGuy.github.io), тогда все заработает.

Кроме этого, переименуйте файл `main.html` в `index.html`. Тогда при открытии [главной](https://thedifferentguy.github.io) вы сразу попадете на вашу [страничку](https://thedifferentguy.github.io/main.html).

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ, я всё поменял, но меня всё так же кидает на главную.

Comment: Сформулируйте вопрос, [отредактируйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1435940/edit) его, добавьте детали. Не очень понятно, что вы хотите. Сейчас при заходе на [главную](https://thedifferentguy.github.io) кидает на главную. А вы хотите чтобы куда?

Comment: Если мой ответ вам помог, то проголосуйте за него (нажмите стрелочку вверх напротив моего ответа) и/или отметьте как правильный (нажмите галочку рядом с ответом).